# defaultValue not working in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is simple question regarding javascript `.value` and `.defaultValue`

Here is my First html

```
<input id="txt" value="Hello">
</input>
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

And corresponding js

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert('Old Value '+ document.getElementById('txt').defaultValue);
    alert('New value ' + document.getElementById('txt').value);
});
```

So the above html by default has `Hello`, now if i remove a few characters and make it `Hel` and press the button, the output that i'm getting is `Old Value Hello` and `New value Hel`

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TPazf/2/)

Now here is my second html

```
<input id="txt" ></input>
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

And the corresponding js

```
$('#txt').val('Hello');
$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert('Old Value '+ document.getElementById('txt').defaultValue);
    alert('New value ' + document.getElementById('txt').value);
});
```

Here if i remove a few characters and make it `Hel` and press the button, the output that i'm getting is `Old Value` and `New value Hel`

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TPazf/1/)

Can any one explain why the difference in defaultValue in both examples

Comment: * Oh the first demo **You have default** `value` in html where in second you don't! `:)` LOL! `<input id="txt" >` vs `<input id="txt" value="Hello">` I reckon! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the default value is set by the intial value of the input field... which is an empty string in the second case... you are changing the value using a script which will not update the `defaultValue`

[defaultValue:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

> The default value as originally specified in HTML that created this
>   object.

You can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to update the value of defaultValue after updating value

```
$('#txt').val('Hello').prop('defaultValue', 'Hello');
```

or

```
$('#txt').val('Hello').prop('defaultValue', function(){
    return this.value
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ch27R/)

Comment: ok..dat works...is there a way to call the above code i.e prop('defaultValue', function(){
    return this.value
}); where ever i have called the .val('Hello') since i have a number of input types of text on a page

Comment: @iJay that is a tricky situation since you may not want to change the value of `defaultValue` on all call to `val(...)`, a proper solution will be is to trigger an event whenever you want to update the `defaultValue`

Comment: is there any default value for html select